# Copy Inherits Value to Base Class

Tags: vb.net

I create a class based on other class. I'm try to assign the class a value in its constructor, but get an error.

> Error  1   'Me' cannot be the target of an assignment.

is there a way to solve it..? Here is a code I've created

```
Public Class tabelDSN   
    Inherits DataTable   
    Public Sub New(ByVal dt As DataTable)  
        Me = dt.Copy()  
    End Sub   
    Default Public ReadOnly Property rw(ByVal idx) As DataRow  
        Get  
            Return Me.Rows(idx)  
        End Get  
    End Property  
End Class
```

Comment: You would have to copy the data from the source table into the current table.  Think about what that code you're trying to execute actually does.  `Me` is the current object so how could the current object assign another object to itself?  That would mean that the current object would have to magically become another object, which doesn't make sense.  Could you magically become another person, or would you have to apply the traits of some other person to yourself?  It's the latter, so that's what has to happen here too.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your tabelDSN class be a wrapper for the DataTable class, by removing the Inherits and adding a private DataTable field to hold the constructor parameter. The code would look like this:

```
Public Class tabelDSN   
    Private _dt as DataTable
    Public Sub New(ByVal dt As DataTable)  
        _dt = dt.Copy()  
    End Sub   
    Default Public ReadOnly Property rw(ByVal idx) As DataRow  
        Get  
            Return _dt.Rows(idx)  
        End Get  
    End Property  
End Class
```